# C# Path operations

Tags: c#

I need to get 
     "`first_level`" and "`second_level\third_level`" from the original path "`first_level\second_level\third_level`", something that splits the path into two part by the first separator. Is there any C# method in .net library that does that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Split overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx) that takes a `count` for the maximum number of substrings to return:

```
string input = @"first_level\second_level\third_level";
string[] result = input.Split(new[] { '\\' }, 2);
foreach (string s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);

// result[0] = "first_level"
// result[1] = "second_level\third_level"
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know there's such an overload of Split

Answer (score 3):

```
string myPath = @"first_level\second_level\third_level";

string[] levels = myPath.Split('\\');

and

    level[0] will be equal to first_level
    level[2] will be equal to second_level
    level[3] will be equal to third_level
```

you asking this?

Comment: Do you want to make more things? Isnt it enough?

Comment: It is. But I don't want to write my own code if there's already such a method existing.

Comment: Hmm I dont know any method if exists. I use Split() method for these scenerios.